With Nuxt, fetching from .NET api always return data with undefined value from API call to a .NET server
As the title said, result is always undefined, event though the calls returns the right value to the frontend according to chrome devtools.
Here is how I call the component that makes the call :
<template>
  <div>Home page</div>
  <button @click="fetchFromApi">Fetch from api</button>
  <div>{{ test }}</div>
</template>

<script setup>
  let test = ref("Unchanged");
  let fetchFromApi = async () => {
    const { data, loading, error } = 
        await useFetch("http://localhost:5000/test", {
              method: "GET",
              mode: "no-cors"
            }
        );
    test.value = data.value;
  }
</script>

Here is the API controller :
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    public TestController()
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public string Get()
    {
        return "Test succeeded!";
    }
}

Here is the 'data' that is I get with useFetch :
{
  dep: undefined,
  __v_isRef: true,
  __v_isShallow: false,
  _rawValue: undefined,
  _value: undefined
}

I can confirm with the network tab in chrome devtools that the response body is "Test succeeded!" so eveything should technically be fine. Also, I have the same issue if I use $fetch :
await $fetch("http://localhost:5000/test", {
              method: "GET",
              mode: "no-cors"
            }
        );

I suspected this was due to the ssr, so I turned off ssr in defineNuxtConfig and it doesn't change anything. What am I doing wrong?
EDIT :
The problem was the "no-cors" which prevented the frontend to access the data returned by the API. Very well detailed in the linked question.

Also when do you console the data? Do you have the same issue with Postman? Do you see your data in the network tab?

Thanks for the response. With fetch, the result I get is an empty object, even though once again the network tab from devtools shows tha tthe body of the response contains the string "Test succeeded!" which is what I'm trying to get. It's not console.loged, I update the value of the 'test' ref display in the component. I get the same result if I console.log the response.

So the console log is empty if you check data or does it have the string? Hm what happens if you try to send an actual object from the backend like { name: "Bob"} rather than a string ?

It's either {} with fetch, or undefined $fetch, or what I specified in the object specified in the question with useFetch. In all the cases I do not get the value that I would expect to get.

What if you send an object rather than a string?

I get the exact same behaviour

Okay then give a try to that endpoint: http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/ do you still have an empty object? I suspect it might be the MIME type response of your backend? This endpoint works well and is nice to troubleshoot such things.

Oh boy I can get the response properly, the problem is not on the frontend then I guess. Thanks a lot I'll be able to find my way out of this then.

Yes, this probably is a backend issue indeed. I unfortunately do not have any clue regarding .NET but it's probably the return type of your server that is not JSON or something alike. You could actually inspect the network tab and compare the headers/response/etc of both your server and the JSONplaceholder one. But that narrows down quite well the bug already yes.

As a matter of fact I had to enable cross origin requests on my dotnet server, the linked question provides the answers to my problem. Thanks again
